# configure error message position in VSCode

Tags: vscode-debugger

I have problem with error /warning in VSCode,
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0Kra.png)

I want to show the error back to bottom `2` now the error show on `1`,

issue in the `1`

- I can't click to open link
- hard to copy message
- text mostly show behind minimap

I hope anyone can help, maybe this configurable
thank you